# How to show "shop by price" in homepage

Tags: magento

I am trying to do multiple search and then submit the info taken from attributes to catalogsearch/advanced/result/? but i have problem only with the price.
For my custom attributes (shape for example) i can give value"shape" and it will post correctly but for the price if i give something like value="price%5Bfrom%5D=1&price%5Bto%5D=150 (this means price 1-150 in magento) it will post it with different characters in the broswer bar, so it will not give me the price.
From what i understand is that i cannot put special symbols like "% , =" but with this way i will get the "hacked" way prices (by advanced search from home page in multiple select dropdowns)
How can i do it?

Sorry if i was not clear enough, English is not my mother language!

Answer (score 1):

The "different characters in the browser bar" results of the browser following section 2.1 and 2.2 of the [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) standard. It's called "Percent Encoding" (also often called "URL encoding").

And of course you *can* use special characters. If you want to use any character which is defined as a *reserved character* according to section 2.2, you just need to encode it properly: `%` as `%25`,   as `%20`, `,` as `%2C` and `=` as `%3D`.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters.

Comment: Thank so much, you point some light here, unfortunately if i am trying to reverse symbol (=) for example i will need to write (%3D) but if i do this it will try to reverse the (%) symbol in the 3D, so it will be after %253D (because %25 is the %). <br><br>
I believe it's some rule that i am trying to "hack" but i need to send price%5Bfrom%5D=1&price%5Bto%5D=111 query as this is my only way to get price 1-111<br>
Any other ideas please?

Comment: p.s. for example if you go to a magento site (i believe even in Google) and use the search with characters like =,% it will do Percent Encoding.<br>How can i reverse?<br>
Use this and write %3D in the search.. <br>it will become %253D
http://www.magentothemes.com/